# excel vba cut from sheet1 and past to sheet2 on last empty row

Tags: excel, vba, paste

I can't figure it out why this code is not working.
On sheet1 it selects from second row until last one not empty and cuts.
On sheet2 it goes to the first empty row and some for reason, it does not paste. :-(

```
Sub Macro1()

     Application.ScreenUpdating = False
     Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
     Application.EnableEvents = False
     
     Application.CutCopyMode = False
     
     ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Protocolo diário").Activate
     ActiveSheet.Rows("2:2").Select
     Range(Selection, Selection.End(xlDown)).Cut
    
     ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Protocolo geral").Activate
     ActiveSheet.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0).Select
     Selection.PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
     
     Application.CutCopyMode = False
     
     ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Protocolo diário").Rows("2:" & Rows.Count).ClearContents
     
     Application.CutCopyMode = False
     
     Application.ScreenUpdating = True
     Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
     Application.EnableEvents = True
    
End Sub
```

Comment: You can't `Cut` and then `PasteSpecial`... it's impossible. Try it manually and you'll see.

Comment: If the original data is just values, then probably best to specify the *Destination* parameter of `Cut`. If the original data is formulas, then you can copy/pastespecial values, then clear the original data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Backup ('Cut') Rows

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub backupData()

     Dim wb As Workbook: Set wb = ThisWorkbook
     
     Dim sws As Worksheet: Set sws = wb.Worksheets("Protocolo diário")
     Dim sLastRow As Long: sLastRow = sws.Cells(sws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
     Dim srg As Range: Set srg = sws.Rows(2).Resize(sLastRow - 1)
     
     Dim dws As Worksheet: Set dws = wb.Worksheets("Protocolo geral")
     Dim dLastRow As Long: dLastRow = dws.Cells(dws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
     Dim drg As Range: Set drg = dws.Rows(dLastRow + 1).Resize(srg.Rows.Count)
     
     drg.Value = srg.Value
     srg.ClearContents
     ' or maybe:
     'srg.Delete

End Sub
```

Comment: it crashed on  `Dim srg As Range: Set srg = sws.Rows(2).Resize(sLastRow - 1)`

Comment: What's the error number and description? If column 1 (`A`) is empty, pick another column in the preceding line of the code.